# Hyperlink in response in Api.ai

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am exploring api.ai now a days for one assignment to develop chat bot. Is there a way to add hyperlinks as a part of default response? I do not want to use Google Assistant, Facebook Messanger, KIK,Slack etc but I want to include hyperlink as a part of Default Response. I explored various blogs but could not find desired answer.

Comment: No, you cannot get hyperlink on Default Response of Diaglogflow. However, you can format hyperlink on your web from your Text Response.

Answer (score 1):

Practically you can't, but there is a hack:

- Choose the response to be card.
- Choose a custom image.
- Embed link in the "next".

[image: Example]

Comment: If you use jovo, you can use basic card + addButton(title, url) as described here https://www.jovo.tech/docs/google-assistant/visual-output#basic-card

Answer (score 0):

No, ideally you can not add a hyperlink in default response of api.ai but there is a workaround that I used in my code. In my case, I have developed my own chat window where before printing, I'm running a check on the response that is coming from api.ai using following function & get that link converted into the clickable format.

```
if(!String.linkify) {
String.prototype.linkify = function() {

// http://, https://, ftp://
var urlPattern = /\b(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9-+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[a-z0-9-+&@#\/%=~_|]/gim;

// www. sans http:// or https://
var pseudoUrlPattern = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;

// Email addresses
var emailAddressPattern = /[\w.]+@[a-zA-Z_-]+?(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+/gim;

return this
.replace(urlPattern, '<a target="_blank" href="$&">$&</a>')
.replace(pseudoUrlPattern, '$1<a target="_blank" href="http://$2">$2</a>')
.replace(emailAddressPattern, '<a href="mailto:$&">$&</a>');
};
}
```